# Сумма цифр двухзначного числа

Tags: javascript

Дано двухзначное число. Найдите сумму его цифр.

Для решения задачи: Создайте переменную num и присвойте ей значение любого положительного двухзначного число от 10 до 99.

Создайте переменную secondDigit, присвойте ей выражение, позволяющее получить вторую цифру числа num (используйте операцию нахождения остатка %).

Создайте переменную firstDigit, присвойте ей выражение, позволяющее получить первую цифру числа num. Создайте переменную sum, присвойте ей значение суммы цифр.

Пример:

```
const number = 456; 
const a = number % 10;
```

Моё решение:

```
const num = 50; 
const secondDigit = num % 10; 
const firstDigit = num % 10; 
const sun = secondDigit * firstDigit;
```

Выдаёт ошибки:

FailПеременная firstDigit вычислена верно expected 5 to equal 0

FailПеременная sum имеет значение sum is not defined

FailПеременная sum равна сумме цифр числа sum is not defined

Comment: `sun` -> `sum`()

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это будет в решении...

Comment: `const sun(!) =. ...` -> `sum is not defined`, ошибку не видите?

Comment: @meine имеет ввиду, что вы назвали переменную не `sum`, как требует условие задачи, а `sun`, из-за чего выдаёт ошибки. И ещё, там у вас произведение чисел (`const sun = secondDigit * firstDigit;`), а в условии задачи требуют присвоить их сумму.

Comment: Простите увидел и исправил. const sum = secondDigit * firstDigit; Ситуация изменилась к лучшему, но ошибка всё же есть... FailПеременная `firstDigit` вычислена верно
expected 5 to equal 0

Comment: 456 не двузначное яисло

Comment: @SergeyfromKhabarovsk, да, только что хотел написать, заметил ещё. `firstDigit` - это первая цифра числа, а вы вычисляете вторую с помощью той же записи, что и `secondDigit`. Первую цифру числа `num` можно вычислить, например, через такую запись: (`let firstDigit = +(num.toString()[0]);`).

Comment: Alexey Ten const number = 456;
const a = number % 10; это лишь приведённый пример решения

Comment: @SergeyfromKhabarovsk Всматривайтесь, пытайтесь для начала сами найти ошибку. В этом вам часто может помочь текст ошибки. Например: вам выдаёт: `FailПеременная sum имеет значение sum is not defined`. Очевидно, что что-то не так с переменной `sum`. Понимание английского языка или наличие переводчика может помочь с переводом. Ведь `sum is not defined` переводится как `sum не определена`, всматриваетесь в код и понимаете, что ошибка в названии переменной.

Comment: egbro Вы правы надо повнимательнее и самому попробовать. Чем именно и занимаюсь;) А вообще судя по всему нужно немного отвлечься, а то разум кипит  от задач за весь день)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var num = 50; 
var firstDigit = num / 10 | 0; 
var secondDigit = num % 10; 
var sum = firstDigit + secondDigit;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var twoDigitSums = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    twoDigitSums[i * 10 + j] = i + j; 
  }
}

function sum(num) {
  return twoDigitSums[num];
}

console.log(sum(57));
console.log(sum(99));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const num = 57;
const secondDigit = num % 10;     // Остаток от деления на 10? → 7
const firstDigit = (num - secondDigit) / 10;     // (57 - 7) / 10 → 5

const sum = secondDigit + firstDigit;

console.log( sum ); // 12
```

Если число, скажем, шестизначное, задолбаетесь так высчитывать каждую цифру. С какого-то момента становится легче превратить число в строку и сразу взять все её цифры:

```js
let num = 111111111;

console.log( ("" + num).split("").reduce((acc, e) => acc + Number(e), 0) ); // 9

/***/

let digits = ("" + num).split("");
let sum = 0;
for( let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++ ) {
  sum += Number(digits[i]);
}

console.log( sum ); // 9
```

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME, спасибо за разбор по полочкам! Вот ответ:  const num = 50; 
const secondDigit = num % 10; 
const firstDigit = (num - secondDigit) / 10; 
const sum = secondDigit + firstDigit; Ошибок нет!
console.log( sum );